# How to update only missing values in R based on parameters

Tags: r

I have data set as below mentioned script

```
library(ggmap)
countries <- c('Ghana', 'Guinea', 'Mali', 'Niger')
withLocation<- data.frame(countries, geocode(countries))
```

once I run the command then I get data like this

```
       countries        lon        lat
1          Ghana  -1.023194   7.946527
2         Guinea  -9.696645   9.945587
3           Mali  -3.996166  17.570692
4          Niger         NA         NA
```

Now I have missing values for 'Niger' and want to update that row only as running the google API with complete list will miss different country, please help me to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know how to select the part of your data frame and get the values which need replacing?

```
na_rows <- is.na(withLocation$lon & withLocation$lat)
withLocation[na_rows, c(2,3)] <- c('update', 'values')
```

I'm not sure this is going to solve your problem, but feel free to write me a comment and let me know what needs improving.

Comment: Interesting use of `&` there... clever.